# Displaying details when clicking a DataGrid row

Tags: wpf

I have a `DataGrid` that displays a list of classes for a professor. What I want to do is to allow the professor to click on a row on the `DataGrid` and then display the students that are in that class.

Is that possible with WPF?

Comment: You can find basic informations on the topic on https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html, below the section "Row Details"

Answer (score 1):

In the datagrid, add the following sections:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding students}">
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the details inline inside the table, @AnsonWoody wrote the answer. If you want to display the details outside in a separate control, use `SelectedItem` of the `DateGrid` or `CurrentItem` of the `CollectionViewSource`.

Assuming your datacontext contains the items in `ClassesWithStudents` and each item has a property `Students`, you could do the following:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panel1">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="classesCollection" Source="{Binding ClassesWithStudents}"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource classesCollection}}">
    </DataGrid>
    <!-- Bind current item with path=/ -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource classesCollection},Path=/Students}"/>
    <!-- Bind selected item -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=dg1,Path=SelectedItem.Students}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Ofcourse the `ContentControl` is only a placeholder. If `Students` is a collection, use something like `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource classesCollection},Path=/Students}"/>` or whatever suits your needs in order to get a nice looking student representation.